# Android alarm to trigger notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I need the Android AlarmManager to trigger a notification.

I'm creating the alarm as follows:

```
    private void createAlarm() {
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent mNotificationReceiverIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,mNotificationReceiverIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()
            + ALARM_DELAY, ALARM_DELAY, mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent);
    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm created");
    }
```

The AlarmNotificationReceiver is

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm Notification received");
}
}
```

I never got to see the logmessage, though. I've seen the alarm firing using "adb shell dumpsys alarm":

```
  u0a54:de.fabian_nick.dailyselfie +709ms running, 0 wakeups:

+709ms 0 wakes 12 alarms: *alarm*:de.fabian_nick.dailyselfie/.AlarmNotificationReceiver
```

(at least if I read this correctly).
So I'm assuming the PendingIntent I created is for some reason not being picked up by the BroadcastReceiver. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmNotificationReceiver"></receiver>
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
        android:name="AlarmNotificationReceiver "
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```